# sql insert with multiple selects

Tags: sql, ms-access, finance

I am trying to make an interest calculation for a loan. I have 2 tables, first table is the loan table that contains the loan amount, interest rate and other data. But interest rate changes daily and is stored on another table. So interest rate must be taken from loan tbl only if a payment is made the same day that loan is created.

Also I need to have amount remained after every payment that is store on tbl payment. So on every payment I need to fill the columns on table payment below. I tried to create a SQL statement to calculate interest rate and another to calculate the amount remained after the payment but cant combine them in one insert statement.

Example for loanid=1 , pay amount=$1000, loanid=29

```
SELECT
    1, 1000 , date(), 
    (IIF(NOT ISNULL(t1.dailyinterest), t1.dailyinterest, t2.interestrate) 
FROM 
    daily AS t1
RIGHT JOIN 
    loanable AS t2 ON (t1.loanid = t2.loanid AND t1.data = date()) 
WHERE 
    t2.loanid = 29)

SELECT
    IIF(NOT ISNULL(pay.amountremained_tobepayed), pay.amountremained_tobepayed, 50000)
FROM 
    payment AS pay 
RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(paymentid) AS id 
     FROM payment 
     WHERE loanid = 29) AS max2 ON pay.paymentid = max2.id
```

loan table

| loanid | clientid | loanamount | interestrate | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 50000 | 0.2 | 05/04/20 |

daily interest table

| clientid | loanid | date | dailyinterest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 06/04/20 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 1 | 07/04/20 | 0.31 |
| 1 | 1 | 08/04/20 | 0.32 |

payment table

| paymenid | loanid | amountpayed | paid_date | paid_interest | paid_pricipal | amountremained_tobepayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, because the code is clearly not MySQL.  Let me just add that I wouldn't recommend MS Access for financial calculations.  You probably need to write VBA code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your query could look something like this.

```
parameters      [loan id] int, 
                [client id] int, 
                [payment date] datetime, 
                [payment amount] currency;

insert      into [payment table] (
    -- payment table column names go here
)
select      
    -- parameters, names of columns in loan_table and 
    -- daily_interest_table, and calculated values go here
from        loan_table
inner join  daily_interest_table
on          loan_table.loanid = daily_interest_table.loanid
and         loan_table.clientid = daily_interest_table.clientid
where       loan_table.loanid = [loan id]
and         loan_table.clientid = [client id]
and         daily_interest_table.date = [payment date];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your sql does not calculate remaining amount after payment. Also interest rate is not always taken from daily interest table. There is one case when payment is done the same day the loan has been created.It takes the interest rate from loan table in this case.

Comment: The commented text (lines beginning --) is left up to the user to complete. I am offering assistance, not a free programming service.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote below sql code but giving me error Syntax error missing operator in query

```
select 29, 1000 , date(), IIF(not IsNull(t1.dailyinterest) ,t1.dailyinterest, t2.interestrate)  * 1000/100 AS inte, 1000 - inte as principal, amtremained
FROM daily AS t1
 RIGHT JOIN loant AS t2
ON (t1.loanid = t2.loanid and t1.data= date())
 inner join
(select IIF(not IsNull(pay.remainedamount), pay.remainedamount, 50000) - principal as amtremained
FROM paymentt AS pay RIGHT JOIN
 (SELECT max(paymentid) AS id FROM paymentt where loanid=29)  AS max2 ON pay.paymentid=max2.id)
on pay.loanid=t1.loanid
```